# How to pass the data from class component to functional component and vice verse

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-component

I want to push some data from one class component to functional component and vice verse. I have researched lot but I didn't get any proper soln.

here My main componennt(class component)

```
import MemberList from './component/AddList'
export default class material extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Members: ''
        };


    }

 render() {

        return (<div> <MemberList data={this.state.Members}/>  </div>
        );
    }
```

in members.js 
I have implemented this functionality
https://codesandbox.io/s/runh6

```
const members = []; //here I want to load the values from class component
function DownshiftMultiple(props) {

  return (
    <Downshift>


        return (
          <div className={classes.container}>


          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Downshift>
  );
}




export default function IntegrationDownshift(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div >

      <DownshiftMultiple classes={classes} />

         </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried to take the value with help of props.
i'm not able to get the data.

so can anyone help to resolve this.

Comment: That should be fine, there is not really much difference between functional/class components in terms of passing data down through props. I can't see how the codesandbox you linked relates to your problem? Do you have a codesandbox example of your implementation not working? At what point are you setting `this.state.Members` to something?

Comment: I have updated the question. On componentdidmount. I will load the data. And I don't know how to add the data to members array in members.js

Comment: check this out https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values from props.

```
function DownshiftMultiple(props) {

  const members = props.members; //here I want to load the values from class component

  return (
    <Downshift>
      return (
        <div className={classes.container}>


        </div>
     );
    }}
   </Downshift>
 );
}
```

Comment: you need to pass `members` as a prop too.